# Line break inside a link title. How do search engines interpret it?

Tags: jquery, seo, jquery-tooltip

I plan to use jquery to display this link title in a little nice format. Now the thing is, I'm not sure how would search engines like it. Is it allowed?

```
<div class="c1"><a href="/page1.php" title="Example of Tomatoes<br />Quality: Excellent<br />Availability: Yeslot">Tomatoes</a> (Yard 88)</div>
```

Comment: It's invalid XHTML. At the very least, you'd need to escape the `<` (not at all allowed in XML attributes). Either way, it's not going to be interpreted as a line break because HTML elements don't/can't exist inside of attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, all attribute contents should be HTML-encoded if they could contain HTML characters.

Otherwise, you risk the browser getting confused about the overall HTML layout.

Comment: Yea that's what I thought. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. If that helps, please don't forget to mark my reply as the answer.